# Bootstrap Button Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I do not want to use `<a>` element to convert a button into a hyperlink.

I have the following buttons:

```
<button class="btn btn-success"> First button</button>
<button class="btn btn-success"> Second button</button>
```

How do I specify a hyperlink (without using `<a>`) and browse to a page when I click on the buttons

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use JavaScript for your solution. `window.location.href` sets the URL for the button.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.location.href='http://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap'">First button</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

can we know why you want the button to be button not link  tag?
would you consider this code helpful to achieve what you want ?

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <a href="http://www.google.com" role="button" class="btn btn-success btn-large">Google Now</a>
```

Comment: Your code will make a "button-like" link, but is not really an answer as he clearly stated "without using `<a>`".